# How do I remove a dependency in an equation with multiple variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a hard time knowing what step to take next in the following problem. I don't need anyone to tell me the answer per se, but I don't know what strategy to use to find the answer. Once I find out what strategy is involved, I can improve this question by modifying it.

Here is the problem:

**Find values of p, j, and k that do not depend on $\mu$.**

And here is the original equation:

\begin{align*}
  (z - \mu) ^ 2 + (\mu - b) ^ 2 = {}& p(\mu - j(z + b)) ^ 2 + k\\
\end{align*}

My strategy is to expand this equation to see if the left and right sides look similar, and they do:

\begin{align*}
  z ^ 2 - 2\mu{z} + \mu ^ 2 + \mu ^ 2 - 2\mu{b} + b ^ 2 = {}& p(\mu - j(z + b))(\mu - j(z + b)) + k\\
  z ^ 2 - 2\mu{z} + 2\mu ^ 2 - 2\mu{b} + b ^ 2 = {}& p(\mu ^ 2 - 2\mu{j}(z + b) + (j(z + b)) ^ 2) + k\\
  z ^ 2 - 2\mu{z} + 2\mu ^ 2 - 2\mu{b} + b ^ 2 = {}& p\mu ^ 2 - 2\mu{p}jz + 2\mu{p}jb + pj(z ^ 2 + 2bz + b ^ 2) + k\\
  z ^ 2 - 2\mu{z} + 2\mu ^ 2 - 2\mu{b} + b ^ 2 = {}& p\mu ^ 2 - 2\mu{p}jz + 2\mu{p}jb + pjz ^ 2 + 2pjbz + pjb ^ 2 + k\\
\end{align*}
Now I see that when I make $p = 2$, the left and right sides of the equation look similar:
\begin{align*}
  z ^ 2 - 2\mu{z} + 2\mu ^ 2 - 2\mu{b} + b ^ 2 = {}& 2\mu ^ 2 - 4\mu{j}z + 4\mu{j}b + 2jz ^ 2 + 4jbz + 2jb ^ 2 + k\\
 \end{align*}
Now I see that when I make $j = \frac{1}{2}$, the left and right sides of the equation look similar:
\begin{align*}
  z ^ 2 - 2\mu{z} + 2\mu ^ 2 - 2\mu{b} + b ^ 2 = {}& 2\mu ^ 2 - 2\mu{z} + 2\mu{b} + z ^ 2 + 2bz + b ^ 2 + k\\
\end{align*}
The problem comes with finding a value $k$ that does not depend on $\mu$:
\begin{align*}
  -2\mu{b} = {}& 2\mu{b} + 2bz + k\\
  k = {}& -4\mu{b} - 2bz\\
\end{align*}
Would I just evaluate the original equation and put $\mu$ on the left with everything else on the right and then substitute the equivalent of $\mu$ in the equation above? Or am I missing a better strategy? (I am happy to read up on the strategy if someone can just identify one for me!)

Thanks in advance. I will check the correct answer and vote up (if possible) anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a discussion.

First of all the 4th equation in your calculation has an error, there will be a square in $j$ in the RHS of the equality and a minus in the $2\mu pjb$ term.

Next, instead of testing numbers with equality I prefer to equate the coefficient of $z,z^2$ and the constant term.

Proceeding as your way I get,

$$z^2-2\mu z+(2\mu ^2-2\mu b+b^2)=(j^2p)z^2+z(-2\mu jp+2j^2pb)+(-2\mu bjp+j^2b^2+p\mu^2+k)$$
Now equating coefficient of $z,z^2,z^0$ we get,

$$j^2p=1---(1)\\-2\mu jp+2j^2pb=-2\mu---(2)\\-2\mu jbp+j^2b^2p+\mu^2p=2\mu^2-2\mu b+b^2---(3)$$
Now solve for $\mu$ in (2) using (1) and finally use (1), (2), $\mu$ to solve for $k$.

Probably: $\mu=\frac{b}{jp-1}$ and $k=b^2(2+\frac{2-p}{(jp-1)^2})$

**If any change is necessary please edit my answer**

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this against the feedback I get from another mathematician (hopefully in a few days) and then either vote this as the right answer or correct and vote it as the right answer. I appreciate the input!